# How to combine 2 Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I'm writing a CRUD rest api and got a problem with merging 2 futures on service layer.

The idea is to insert Entity into db, and then retrieve all the generated by db values by id.

I tried andThen() as it is in Java, but it can't return Future[Entity], it says  it is still Future[Long]

```
class Service {
  def find(id: Long): Future[Option[Entry]] = db.run(repo.findEntry(id))

  //TODO Fails: Expression of type Future[Long] doesn't conform to expected type Future[Option[Entity]]
  def insert(): Future[Option[Entry]] = db.run(repo.insertEntry())
            .andThen { case Success(id) =>
                find(id)
            }
}

class Repository {
  def findEntry(id: Long): DBIO[Option[Entry]] =
    table.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption

  def insertEntry()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Long] =
    table returning table.map(_.id) += Entry()
}
```

I feel like the answer is easy enough, but just can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`andThen` is for side-effects, it still returns the original result (of the first Future).

You want `flatMap`.

```
 db.run(repo.insertEntry())
   .flatMap( id => find(id) )
```

`flatMap` also comes with a special syntax that most people find more readable (after they get used to it), especially if there are more steps to it:

```
 for {
   id <- db.run(repo.insertEntry())
   entry <- find(id)
 } yield entry
```

Comment: Tried to edit `yield id` to `yield entry`, as it seems like an obvious typo, but a couple of users with no activity in scala or related FP tags both rejected it. I'm a little peeved so leaving a comment for the answerer or higher-karma scala user to edit if they agree.

Comment: @Score_Under Yeah, I saw that. Thanks for the correction, I overrode the objecting bystanders.